# rest API in xampp e-moodle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to get data from xampp emoodle that is mostly used for objective exam questions. My question is. Is it possible to get student results as json through api in another web app instead of manually downloading it as Excel or other format available

Answer (score 0):

Xampp is local server. you can get data from online website.
you can get student results as json through api from another online website.

Comment: Yeah I got that, actually what I want is to get data from an open source app through rest API. Assuming it doesn't have rest api. Is it possible for me to implement the rest API in it and how will I do that. I need a guide